# Jasmine test - undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a following structure:

```
el(
  "div",
  {
    class: "parentClass"
  },
  el(
    "div",
    {
      class: "childClass",
      oncreate: ({ dom }) => {
        dom.parentNode.classList.add("childCreated");
      }
    }
  )
)
```

I need to test that `oncreate` adds the `created` class to parentNode class.

I tried following:

```
childDom.oncreate(childDom);
expect(parentCSS).toEqual("parentClass childCreated")
```

but I get `undefined is not an object (t.parentNode)` error

I expect the test to run without errors